# how to filter by event in aws lambda snowball?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have and preordered AWS snowball that has been ordered with all its events raised.

I need to know what the event is that is running (it will send a lambda when its shipped and when it arrives back to amazon, how can i get different operations for this?)

The Examples are too simple

my lambda is

```
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var httpOptions = {
        host: "myip",
        port: '80',
        path: "/createFirs",
        method: "GET"
    };

    if (false) {
        http.get(httpOptions, function(response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log(chunk);
                //context.done(null, chunk);
                context.succeed(event);
            });

            response.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                context.done(err, null);
            });
        });
    } else {
        context.done(new Error("snowball lambda isn't complete yet"));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Information about **AWS Import/Export Snowball jobs** is available via the [DescribeJob API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/ug/API_DescribeJob.html).

There are also [notifications generated by Snowball](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/ug/notifications.html) that are sent via Amazon SNS. Notifications [include](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/ug/using-console.html#get-status-of-job):

- In transit
- Delivered
- Importing
- Completed

You can **subscribe an AWS Lambda function to an Amazon SNS topic**, so that the Lambda function is called when the Snowball notification is received.

Comment: I understand that. but ow do i act by code to each event ?

Comment: without creating multiple lambdas and sns notification types?
i want to filter by event type in the code.

Comment: Lambda includes a testing template for simulating triggers by SNS, but not for generating Snowball-specific notifications. Also, I can't think of an easy way to simulate Snowball events without actually ordering a snowball. I'd suggest starting starting by turning on SNS with email notification to see what data comes through when you next use Snowball.

Comment: not directly connected, but just so you know (i didn't) you dont HAVE to transport with a snowball, you can send them a regular HDD. And I recommend it, snowball status is iffy, fails in network connections on simple hubs and switches, you can't query the snowball to know EXACTLY how many bytes a file was written. cli fails with wierd errors. dont use it imho